# Why recylerView items removed when BottomSheetDialogFragment disappear

Tags: android-fragments, android-dialogfragment

i am trying to create a list of different companies using recylerView. so whats happening i show bottom sheet fragment where i populate list of different companies names. i ask user to add a different name of any company if they want. i am getting company name from dialog box and adding that name into recylerView list.

but when the bottom sheet disappear i lost the name of the company name added by the user. i want to keep that name of company added by the user. basically i want to create a listview and want to get the listView item from the user using Dialog box.

hope i explain my question in details. below is my code.

```
public class Item
  {
public String companyName;

public Item(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;
}

public String getCompanyName() {
    return companyName;
}

public void setCompanyName(String companyName) {
    this.companyName = companyName;}}`
```

below it my adapter class

```
public class CustomAdapter_1 extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter_1.myViewHolder> {
List<Item> customAdapters;
Context context;

public CustomAdapter_1(Context context, List<Item> customAdapters) {
    this.customAdapters = customAdapters;
    this.context = context;

}


@NonNull
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from ( parent.getContext () ).inflate ( R.layout.custom_adapter_1, parent, false );
    myViewHolder myViewHolder = new myViewHolder ( v );
    return myViewHolder;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull myViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.radioButton.setText ( customAdapters.get ( position ).getCompanyName () );

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return customAdapters.size ();
}


public class myViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    RadioButton radioButton;
    TextView textView;

    public myViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super ( itemView );
        radioButton = (RadioButton) itemView.findViewById ( R.id.rdbtn1 );


    }
}

public void AddItem(Item item, int position) {
    customAdapters.add ( position, item );

}}
```

and this is my fragment

```
public class CustomFragment_1 extends BottomSheetDialogFragment {

private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private CustomAdapter_1 mAdapter;
ArrayList<Item> listOfItem = new ArrayList<> ();

String cName, listString;
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer ();
Button btn;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate ( R.layout.fragment_custom_1, container, false );


    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById ( R.id.customRV );
    btn = (Button) view.findViewById ( R.id.button1 );
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager ( getContext () );
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager ( linearLayoutManager );


    mAdapter = new CustomAdapter_1 ( getContext (), listOfItem );
    recyclerView.setAdapter ( mAdapter );
    listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "Company 1" ) );
    listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "Company 2" ) );
    listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "Company 3" ) );


    btn.setOnClickListener ( new View.OnClickListener () {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final FlatDialog flatDialog = new FlatDialog ( getActivity () );
            flatDialog.setTitle ( "Company Name" )
                    .setSubtitle ( "Please add the name of the company" )
                    .setFirstTextFieldHint ( "Company Name" )
                    .setFirstButtonText ( "ADD" )
                    .setSecondButtonText ( "CANCEL" )
                    .withFirstButtonListner ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            cName = flatDialog.getFirstTextField ();
                            listOfItem.add ( new Item ( flatDialog.getFirstTextField () ) ) ;
                            flatDialog.dismiss ();

                        }
                    } )
                    .withSecondButtonListner ( new View.OnClickListener () {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            flatDialog.dismiss ();
                        }
                    } )
                    .show ();


        }
    } );

    return view;
}}
```

i really appreciate your time and i thanks all for their time. thanks

Comment: You just need to add item to the listview that is being shown in the recyclerview and then just refresh the recyclerview adapter and it will be done.

Comment: would you please explain me in code i really appreciate thanks

Comment: i am able to add item but when the bottom sheet disappear i lost the added name

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

On Dialog's submit button click:

```
listOfItem.add ( new Item ( "Company 1" ) );
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Instead if "Company 1" as a value, you can put the value from the edittext which you are taking input from.

Comment: thanks for your reply but i am able to add item in the listView as you said but when bottom sheet disappear i lost the added name in your case Company 1.

Comment: yes i am taking value from editText but still is not working